# camera plugin ibm worklight not working

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I am using Worklight v5.0.6 and have downloaded a sample app from Apache Cordova site for accessing the device camera.

I gave all the appropriate permissions in AndroidManifest.xml, but when I run it in the emulator the buttons don't work, i.e. the functions aren't being called and I am not getting access to the camera.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Capture Photo</title>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.6.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

var pictureSource;   // picture source
var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value 

// Wait for Cordova to connect with the device
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

// Cordova is ready to be used!
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
    destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
}

// Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
//
function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
  // Uncomment to view the base64 encoded image data
  // console.log(imageData);

  // Get image handle
  //
  var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');

  // Unhide image elements
  //
  smallImage.style.display = 'block';

  // Show the captured photo
  // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
  //
  smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
}

// Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
//
function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
  // Uncomment to view the image file URI 
  // console.log(imageURI);

  // Get image handle
  //
  var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');

  // Unhide image elements
  //
  largeImage.style.display = 'block';

  // Show the captured photo
  // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
  //
  largeImage.src = imageURI;
}

// A button will call this function
//
function capturePhoto() {
  // Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
    destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL });
}

// A button will call this function
//
function capturePhotoEdit() {
  // Take picture using device camera, allow edit, and retrieve image string  
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 20,allowEdit:true,
    destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL });
}

// A button will call this function
//
function getPhoto(source) {
  // Retrieve image file location from specified source
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, 
    destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: source });
}

// Called if something bad happens.
// 
function onFail(message) {
  alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="capturePhoto();">Capture Photo</button> <br>
<button onclick="capturePhotoEdit();">Capture Editable Photo</button> <br>
<button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY);">From Photo Library</button><br>
<button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM);">From PhotoAlbum</button><br>
<img style="display:none;width:60px;height:60px;" id="smallImage" src="" />
<img style="display:none;" id="largeImage" src="" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is your question resolved? mark as answered.

Answer (score 2):

This is not related to Worklight, but to Cordova.

If you are taking a Cordova sample app (rather than a Worklight sample app), you can't run it using Worklight, because it's not a Worklight project(!).

If you want to access device features (such as the camera), using a Worklight application, then:

1. Create a new Worklight project and application
2. Add the environment (Android for example)
3. Follow the [Cordova Camera API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html)

You should also read the following training modules to understand how Cordova and Worklight work together: [Adding native functionality to hybrid apps with Apache Cordova](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#cordova)

Answer (score 0):

Though answering to an older question but it will help others.

Its **very easy** to call and use Camera feature in a Worlight project.

For instance; to **open Camera**

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccessCallBack, onFailCallBack, { 
        quality: 50,
        sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI
    });
```

to **open gallery**

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccessCallBack, onFailCallBack, { 
        quality: 50,
        sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI
    });
```

**[Here](https://github.com/aahad/IBMWorklight/tree/master/WLCameraApp)** is a sample code that might help as well.